# Output the DC average value of a waveform

Tags: rms

I have the task of designing a circuit that will, given a sine or square wave as input, output the RMS value of that input. I believe this task essentially has three parts

1. Squaring circuit
2. Averaging network (to get mean value)
3. Square rooting network

The first part wasnt too bad. I hooked up an [AD633 IC](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD633.pdf) with X1/Y1 as the input and X2/Y2/Z grounded. The part that I am stuck on is the Averaging network. I believe I need to do something similar to an integrator circuit however I'm not too sure what variations on that need to be made.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach a sketch of what the signal looks like, or at least a better description?  Is it zero-mean AC?

Comment: Yeah - I am dealing with a simple 5V sine wave at 500Hz and 5KHz. After it passes through the AD633 I am getting the expected 2.5V (25V/10V) peak output and respective 1KHz or 10KHz frequency components depending on if I use 500Hz or 5KHz for my input frequency.

Comment: A simpler option might be an RMS-to-DC converter chip which does all three processes: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/AD8436JCPZ-WP/AD8436JCPZ-WP-ND/2780731. Or even easier these days, just digitize the signal and do the processing with DSP.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are stuck on the 'averaging network', inbetween the squaring multiplier and the square root circuit. Averaging is usually just a low pass filter.

Assuming you don't synchronize the filtering with your input waveform it's going to be a trade-off between output ripple and response time to changes in the input.

Ideally you would integrate the value over an integral number of cycles of the input waveform, as you seem to be thinking (and divide by the time to get the mean), but usually that's impractical and/or unnecessary.

Comment: So would I be trying to attenuate all frequencies above my input frequency? Or because I am trying to get DC I should be trying to eliminate most/all of the frequency components? Thanks for the help

Comment: Finding rms of an AC signal that includes 0 does not simply involve a low pass filter.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The averaging is just a low pass filter after squaring and before taking the square root. DC squared, then low pass filtered and then square rooted is the correct RMS value of DC (unchanged in magnitude and absolute value).

Comment: You are trying to greatly attenuate the lowest frequency content of your input signal.

Comment: Yes, low pass filtering preceded by rectification (usually) or squaring (above and beyond for most purposes), but not "just" a low pass filter, which is what this answer sounds like.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Hmm.. well the 'question' was that he was stuck on the averaging network, but I'll make it more clear in case it is confusion. Without square and square root, it obviously won't really measure RMS, just RMS-scaled average.

Comment: Thanks-- its especially important given the disconnect between the title and the question.  A low pass filter certainly *will* give you DC!  I wasn't sure if you were answering the question or the title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this method would work for a square wave, but if we consider it an infinite sum of sine waves, I don't see why it wouldn't. Here's what I would do:

1. Diode bridge to rectify your signal.
2. Feed signal to appropriate low pass filter.

To get a perfectly clean output will require good filtering. I would advise against integrating as this would require knowing the signals frequency. The goal is to use the filter to pick out the lowest term in the Fourier Sum (i.e. the average of the signal).

Comment: The rectification is presumably part of the "squaring network".

Comment: Right. Bascially the diode bridge avoids the need to square then square-root the signal, and just average it instead. Fair, since the signal is now entirely positive in the idealized approximations (?).